# Avoiding Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Manufacturers):

```
Manufacturer    ID
------------------
Lagun            1
Hurco            2
Mazak            3
Haas             4
```

Then another table (inventory):

```
Shop     Lathe    DrillPress    CNC    Mill    ID
-------------------------------------------------
ABC Inc    2          1           3      3       1
VECO       4          2           1      2       2
```

I need to end up with:

```
Shop     Lathe    DrillPress   CNC     Mill
--------------------------------------------  
ABC Inc  Hurco    Lagun        Mazak   Mazak
VECO     Haas     Hurco        Lagun   Hurco
```

I have this:

```
SELECT 
     Shop, M1.Manufacturer AS Lathe, M2.Manufacturer AS DrillPress, 
     M3.Manufacturer AS CNC, M4.Manufacturer AS Mill 
FROM Inventory I
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers M1 ON M1.ID = I.LstFlowMan
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers M2 ON M2.ID = I.LstFiltFlowMan
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers M3 ON M3.ID = I.LstFilterMan
LEFT JOIN Manufacturers M4 ON M4.ID = I.LstEmitMan
```

I'm probably missing a better way with a PIVOT or CROSS APPLY or something.

Comment: I would bet that with such query you will get the best performance (of course if there are indexes). Other queries may look nicer but most probably they will perform worse

Comment: Possibly but if you have many fields in inventory, it gets long.  Also, if you're looking for just one record i.e. WHERE I.ID = 2, I wonder which way would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @LauDec, here is the SQLServer Version:

```
select * from (
select SHOP, KEYS, MANUFACTURER from
(select SHOP, LATHE,DRILLPRESS,CNC,MILL from inventory) a
    unpivot (val for keys in (LATHE,DRILLPRESS,CNC,MILL)) as unpvt
     JOIN Manufacturers M ON M.ID=VAL
) a
PIVOT (
MAX(MANUFACTURER)
FOR keys in (LATHE,DRILLPRESS,CNC,MILL)
) as pp
```

Comment: See?  I knew there was a better way.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
SELECT i.shop, 
       lathe = Max(CASE WHEN i.lathe = m.id THEN m.manufacturer END), 
       drillpress = Max(CASE WHEN i.drillpress = m.id THEN m.manufacturer END), 
       mill = Max(CASE WHEN i.mill = m.id THEN m.manufacturer END),
       cnc = Max(CASE WHEN i.cnc= m.id THEN m.manufacturer END)
FROM   manufacturers m 
       JOIN inventory i 
         ON m.id IN ( i.lathe, i.drillpress, i.cnc, i.mill ) 
GROUP  BY i.shop
```

Consider changing the table structure of `inventory` table.

**inventory :** `Shop,MachineType,ManufacturerID`

Then you can use Pivot/Cross tab to get the result

Answer (score 2):

You can UNPIVOT JOIN and RE-PIVOT

```
SELECT * FROM (
select SHOP, KEYS, MANUFACTURER from
 inventory unpivot ( val for keys in ("LATHE","DRILLPRESS","CNC","MILL"))
 JOIN Manufacturers M ON M.ID=VAL
) PIVOT (
MAX(MANUFACTURER)
FOR keys in ('LATHE','DRILLPRESS','CNC','MILL')
)
```

Comment: Oracle syntax. Will have to adapt it for sql-server